# Goat Simulator Alpha Blending Graphics Card Error

Tags: goat-simulator

I just bought and played this game yesterday (on Steam) without a problem and have a decent graphics card (AMD Radeon HD 7800).

**I tried to play today and got this error:**

your video card does not support alpha blending with floating point render targets (D3DFMT_A16B16G16R16F), which is required to run this game. Exiting...

Tried uninstalling the game and restarting the computer without it changing anything.

Comment: Here is someone with a similar problem that solved it by downloading a specific driver. https://steamcommunity.com/app/554220/discussions/0/1291816880495945379/

Comment: That sounds like a good route to explore - thanks for the link!